# Synchronize struct in C for Threading

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I have a global struct that I use within threads, that I create utilizing `pthread.h`.
There are concurrent threaded events updating variables within it. 
Therefore my data within the struct often is out of sync, as I found out via extensive debugging.

There's no keyword like "`synchonized`" (Java background) in C afaik. So how do I block the data-structure to keep it valid?

My struct is:

```
struct thread_data 
{
   int nr;
   int time;
};
struct thread_data thread_data_array[MAX_THR];
```

MAX_THR is defined as 10 e.g..

My data get passed to the new thread with `pthread_create`:

```
pthread_create(&threads[num_threads], NULL, Thread_Fkt, &thread_data_array[num_thread]);
```

Sometimes Threads are created within other threads. There's no linear termination. Does C provide a synchronized set of data-structures?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 8):

You should probably look into pthread [`mutex`](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html) :

> A mutex is a MUTual EXclusion device,
>   and is useful for protecting shared
>   data structures from concurrent
>   modifications, and implementing
>   critical sections and monitors.

Comment: I'd also make the struct opaque and move all the access/mutate operations into functions, so you know you have everything in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Threads are not part of C itself but of the operating system.

The "pthread" in `pthread_create` stands for POSIX threads. There are several utilities in POSIX to synchronize between threads. It would certainly depend on what you want to achieve exactly.

```
pthread_mutex_t
pthread_barrier_t
pthread_cond_t
```

You can find first information about these by consulting the man pages of their "init" functions, e.g

```
man pthread_mutex_init
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your `num_threads` variable is global and shared between all threads.  As an example of using pthreads mutexes, you would protect this variable by declaring an associated mutex:

```
int num_threads = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mtx_num_threads = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Then whenever you access the variable, you need to take a lock on the mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_num_threads);
new_thread = num_threads++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_num_threads);

pthread_create(&threads[new_thread], NULL, Thread_Fkt, &thread_data_array[new_thread]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to clarify the two other answers.

Unlike in other languages, in "C", you can't just declare a structure as "protected" and have the compiler/libraries/framework abstract all the synchronization for you.

pthread mutexes *are* the way to go, but it is a *manual* process in which *you* have to determine which *sections of code* (as opposed to which *data structures*) are to be protected, and to put that protection in your code.

This consists of determining which pieces of *code* would touch these shared data structures, and put the code *inside* the appropriate pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock statements.

Comment: I want to add that the "other compiler/lib/fw" do definitely *not* abstract "all the synchronization" for you, especially not for languages with "synchronized" keywords like Java or C#, as you seem to imply.  Inherently thread-safe &&|| lock-free data-structures exist in C too, though of course they are not in the standard-library, and therefore not as accessible for the non-initiated, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes are slow.  See if you can get away with atomic operations.